# How to call service from component which are in different files?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, axios

```
filename: service.js
let getCorporateRequests = function() {
   let url = "http://corptest.mocklab.io/thing/2";
   Vue.axios.get(url).then((response) => {
     return response;
   })
}
```

and in component

```
service.getCorporateRequests().then(function(data){
 console.log(data);
})
```

It is giving "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined".

Comment: Are you exporting the function in `service.js` an importing it in the component?

Comment: Yes. That was my bad. Thank you. returning a promise will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After you export the `getCorporateRequests()` and import it in the component

Your `getCorporateRequests` function is not returning a promise so you cannot use `getCorporateRequests().then()`

so make your `getCorporateRequests()` return a promise

```
filename: service.js
let getCorporateRequests = function() {
   let url = "http://corptest.mocklab.io/thing/2";
   return Vue.axios.get(url);
}
```

now in your component you can chain a `then()` as follows:

```
service.getCorporateRequests().then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
})`
```